# ruby code error: '+'no implicit conversion of Integer into String

Tags: ruby

Getting runtime code error: In '+': no implicit conversion of Integer into String TypeError

```
num = 5;
puts ("this is number: " + num);
```

Actual Result:

> runtime code error: In '+': no implicit conversion of `Integer` into `String` `TypeError`

Expected Result - I should see printed statement -

> this is number: 5

Comment: The recommended way to include variables is with string interpolation: `"this is number: #{num}"`

Answer (score 19):

Don’t put spaces between method names and opening parentheses in the first place.

The cause of the error one cannot add numbers to strings, ruby prevents implicit coercion. One might use string interpolation:

```
puts "this is number: #{num}"
```

or convert the number to string explicitly:

```
puts("this is number: " + num.to_s)
```

---

*Sidenote:* semicolon at the end of the line is redundant and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert the variable `num` into string

```
puts("this is number: "+ num.to_s)
```

refer the official docs https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/09/ruby-conversion-methods/